# Redirect users from whence they came

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, let's say we have some Widgets and a widgets controller and these widgets are in views distributed all over the site across a number of controller.

With Rails, using the normal conventions, a user once a widget edit is completed gets redirected to the widgets_path.  However, in this instance, we want to send them back to the #index of whatever controller they came from.

Question is, what's the best way to implement this?  Sure we can use cookies to store the last controller visited and such like, but is there a better way?

Comment: Hi Neil, I wonder whether my question was helpful for you. Would you mind to accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to look into `request.referer` and see if you can use it to get back to the `#index` of the referring controller.

Answer (score -2):

Look into `redirect_to :back`, as discussed in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/131-going-back).

Comment: This will send you back to the page that issued the request, i.e, the edit form, NOT the index that they originally came from.